# Task with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

To study the pointers I have tried to solve this task

```
int main()
{
    char buf1[100] = "Hello";
    char buf2[100] = "World";
    char *ptr1 = buf1+2;
    char *ptr2 = buf2+3;
    strcpy(ptr1, buf2);
    strcpy(ptr2, buf1);
    cout << ptr1 << endl << ptr2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Try to solve without lookinkg on the answer:

> World
>  HeWorld

Personally, I could not solve. I realized only the first few steps:

1. Declares an array of type char dimension of 100 units. Arrays are initialized by text.

   `char buf1[100] = "Hello";`
   `char buf2[100] = "World";`
2. Is declared a pointer `ptr1`, which will indicate the address of `buf1` offset in two units. For clarity, we remove the two characters of `buf1` and see that `ptr1` points to the first letter `l` in the word `Hello`.

   `char *ptr1 = buf1+2;`
3. Cross out of `buf2` first three characters and see that the pointer `ptr2` points to the letter `l` in the word `World`.

   `char *ptr2 = buf2+3;`

`strcpy` function is copying. I do not understand what and where copied.

Comment: Decide whether you are learning about C or C++.  (The `cout` suggests C++.)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy

Comment: Have you read the `strcpy()` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)? Looked up any [`strcpy()` examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm)?

Comment: When you are setting strings to char pointers you dont need to specify size. So `char buf1[] = "Hello";` and `char buf2[] = "World";` is the "correct" way.

Comment: @valter That would be the wrong way here, because the code adds data to the buffers with the `strcpy`.

Comment: I was speeking in a general manner.

Comment: @valter And you were wrong in a general manner.

Comment: @interjay That was very funny. I can not stop laughing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial memory contents are:

```
buf1            buf2
v               v
Hello           World
  ^                ^
  ptr1             ptr2
```

The `strcpy` function copies its second argument into the first.`strcpy(ptr1, buf2)` copies the contents of `buf2` ("World") into `ptr1`. So now we have:

```
buf1            buf2
v               v
HeWorld         World
  ^                ^
  ptr1             ptr2
```

`strcpy(ptr2, buf1)` copies contents of `buf1` ("HeWorld") into `ptr2`. The result is:

```
buf1            buf2
v               v
HeWorld         WorHeWorld
  ^                ^
  ptr1             ptr2
```

So in the end, `ptr1` points to the string "World", and `ptr2` points to the string "HeWorld".

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you know that `ptr1` pointing to `llo` and `ptr2` pointing to `ld`.
Now see the first `strcpy`

```
strcpy(ptr1, buf2);
```

this will copy `World` to `buf1` frow where `ptr1` points to, so it actually points `World` now. Hence printing `ptr1` will print `World`.
Since `buf1` (after decay) and `ptr1` are pointing to the different elements (`l` (first) of `Hello` and `l` of world string respectively), any modification made to `ptr1` will reflected to `buf1`. So, `buf1[]` now becomes `HeWorld`.
Since the original string has been modified and hence `ptr2` is not pointing any longer to `l`. Now it points to `W` of the string `HeWorld`.
Now see  the second `strcpy`.

```
 strcpy(ptr2, buf1);
```

Now this will starts coyying `HeWorld` from where `ptr2` points to. Hence printing `ptr2` prints `HeWorld`.